# Reporting Services Reports for anonymous users in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SharePoint site which has two kinds of SSRS reports public and private. Public reports does not need any kind of authentication, they should be visible to anyone visiting the site. Basically Anonymous access for public reports and secure access for private reports.

I have searched a lot about anonymous access for SSRS reports in SharePoint and found out that it is one of the requirement for Reporting Services Integration with SharePoint. Is there any work around for this, so that I could display public reports in my SharePoint Site? Any help on this very much appreciated!!

I am using SharePoint Server 2010, SQL Reporting Services 2008 & SQL Server 2008. I can use SQL Reporting Services 2012, if needed.

Thanks
AJ

Comment: Is this SSRS and Sharepoint Integrated installation, or are you just using the Report Viewer and Report List webparts in sharepoint? You can grant everyone in a domain access to the report in the SSRS report manager by adding 'everyone' or 'anonymous' but that is not advisable. Rather have a group that everyone belongs to and grant that group read access to the folder on report manager where all the pubic reports are kept. The Sharepoint permissions work a similar way, you can control the link audience and the page permissions using groups.